# Debian/Ubuntu preseed generator?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, preseed

All of these questions are related to the preseed support in the Debian
Installer: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed

Is there a means, perhaps a .ubeb Debian-Installer extension, by which
I could capture all the selections from an interactive installation session
into a valid preseed.txt file?

Is there away to pause the interactive installer after installation, before
reboot, to apply my postinstall d-i preseed/late_command script manually
(and have that captured in aforementioned file)?

Is there a way to launch the netconsole (ssh daemon support) while still allowing the Debian-Installer to continue an automated installation according to the rest of the contents of the preseed file?  (So that I can remotely debug preseed/installation issues)?

What's currently the best forum for such detailed questions on D-I and preseeding?

Is there a package or framework for maintaing a set of preseed, pxelinux.cfg/* and other files (/etc/dnsmasq.d/* or ISC dhcpd configuration inclusion templates?) under git with some push/deployment scripts to update the live production environment?  (In particular I'd want to have some a framework before attempting to add MD5 checks for my preseed files).

Are there any plans to add SHA3 or SHA256 checksums to the preseed support?
Or to port OpenBSD's signify (https://www.openbsd.org/papers/bsdcan-signify.html) or something like it to Debian/Ubuntu?

Is there a guide or HOWTO on starting the Debian Installer ... for an automated preseed installation from a network booted "Live" instance (perhaps one running under: https://www.reversengineered.com/2014/05/17/building-and-booting-debian-live-over-the-network/)?